# How to customize css borders like google?

Tags: css, reactjs

So I would like to have a similar border to Google's UI in there documentation in Firebase. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/
You can see in the big blue box under the navbar there is a list of tabs. How could I achieve adding an bottom border to my tabs by also having the curved radius at the top? I understand how to use css to create a bottom border but i am clueless in how to add the top curves.

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    border-bottom: 2px Solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: Right-click and Inspect the tab. Notice that the effect is achieved via an `::after` pseudo-element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i try to fix this with border top left and right properties:
have a look, this might help you

```css
#example1 {
  border: 2px solid #0277bd;;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div>Document</div>
<div id="example1">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, hi please Let me know, is this solution works for you or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link::after {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 5px;

}
```

They are actually adding a pseudo-element via `::after` and customising it.
You can customise this style as per your wish.